# How to fix reading from till to date and time mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

On my testpage i have 2 bootstrap datetime pickers.
When the user selects a start date/time and a end date/time and push the button the screen will be filled by data from sql database.
But i have trouble reading from the right time, date is no problem.

The code what i have is this.:

```
$date=$_POST['q'];
$date=explode(' ',$date);
echo "Date".': '.$date[0]."<br/>";
echo "Time".': '.$date[1]."<br/>";

$date1=$_POST['q1'];
$date1=explode(' ',$date1);
echo "Date".': '.$date1[0]."<br/>";
echo "Time".': '.$date1[1]."<br/>";

$a1 = $_POST['a1'];
$q = $date[0];
$q1 = $date1[0];
$q2 = $date[1];
$q3 = $date1[1];

$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * 
                            FROM `metingen` 
                            WHERE (Datum >= '$q' AND Datum <= '$q1') 
                            and (Tijd >= '$q2' AND Tijd <= '$q3') 
                            ORDER BY Id DESC");
```

Its not pritty but witout the tijd(time) its works great, with tijd(time) i miss data.

The date and time i split, as you can see , because the database what i want to use is not made by me, so the date is a seperated column and also time a seperated and both are also text.

if i echo the explode date/time a see.:

```
Date: 15-02-2019
Time: 01:00:32
Date: 16-02-2019
Time: 22:55:33
```

But the data what i get is from 15-2-2019 00:30:56 and till 15-2-2019 22:11:08

I don't see all the dates i miss dates from the 16 and i get dates before my start time.

I think i have something wrong in my sql rule but , i don't know what.
can somebody help me please.

This is my create and insert code of my table (i shorted it in a bit).:

```
    CREATE TABLE `metingen` (
     `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Datum` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Tijd` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `metingen`
--

INSERT INTO `metingen` (`Id`, `Datum`, `Tijd`) VALUES
(1, '17-1-2019', '10:31:39'),
(4, '18-1-2019', '10:30:01'),
(40, '28-1-2019', '23:59:42'),
(41, '28-1-2019', '00:50:12'),
(42, '29-1-2019', '02:00:42'),
(49, '29-1-2019', '06:22:53'),
(56, '5-2-2019', '19:35:02'),
(236, '13-2-2019', '13:58:43')

ALTER TABLE `metingen`
  ADD KEY `Id` (`Id`);


ALTER TABLE `metingen`
  MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=319;
```

Comment: your stored date in which formate ? (DB date formate)?

Comment: Whether they are strings in your database or strings in your application code, always store date and time as a single entity in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s', and using the correct data type, where appropriate.

Comment: as text, just what i mentiond in my text. The db is a old one.

Comment: Is there a reason why the format in your database is different from the format that you have as input? In the database you don't have the pre-padded zeroes in the dates, which you *do* have in the input. Why this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not store date and time as separate fields in your database. You should just combine them into one [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) field in your database. You should then insert and compare such datetime values in one of the [supported literal formats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html), such as `YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s`

Now back to your original situation. The problem is that you require the time condition also when the table's date is strictly between the two extreme dates (not equal to either of them). In that case there should be no constraint on the time part: all times would be OK on such days.

So here is how the SQL would look:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       metingen 
WHERE      ( Datum > '$q'  OR ( Datum = '$q'  AND Tijd >= '$q2' ) )
      AND  ( Datum < '$q1' OR ( Datum = '$q1' AND Tijd <= '$q3' ) )
ORDER BY   Id DESC
```

But again, this is not the best practice.

If you have stored your dates as `varchar` (not as `date`), using the `D-M-YYYY` format, while your input is `DD-MM-YYYY`, then it becomes even more complex (and slow):

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       metingen 
WHERE      ( STR_TO_DATE(Datum, '%d-%m-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('$q', '%d-%m-%Y') 
                  OR ( STR_TO_DATE(Datum, '%d-%m-%Y') = STR_TO_DATE('$q', '%d-%m-%Y')   
                       AND Tijd >= '$q2' ) )
      AND  ( STR_TO_DATE(Datum, '%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('$q1', '%d-%m-%Y')
                  OR ( STR_TO_DATE(Datum, '%d-%m-%Y') = STR_TO_DATE('$q1', '%d-%m-%Y') 
                       AND Tijd <= '$q3' ) )
ORDER BY   Id DESC
```

Another issue is that you inject strings that are posted to the page, and so they are user-driven. This represents a [SQL Injection vulnerabilty](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Instead you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and pass the datetime strings as parameters.

Comment: I will try your code later this evening, thx. But for the record , this is not my databade, it is a old one and not made by me. I can't change it because other programs are running from it , so i must work with what i get :(

Comment: sorry same result.

Comment: Which part of my answer did you try? The SQL I provided? Are you sure you used the conditions and brackets exactly as I provided them?

Comment: Also, could you provide in your question the `create` statement of your table, and some sample data inserted with `insert into` statements? That way I can know how exactly the date/times are formatted in your table. For instance, I'm getting the feeling your dates might be stored as `varchar` and that the format used is not ISO. That would complicate things even more.

Comment: I edit my first post so i could past my insert code and create code.